# How to convert a string or data into QR Code in Node Js

Tags: node.js, qr-code

I need to convert user data into a QR Code and show it in the web browser what is the best way to generate QR Code in node js and show it in user browser

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should look at [qrcode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qrcode) library

This is an exemple of basic usage :

```
var QRCode = require('qrcode')

QRCode.toDataURL('I am a pony!', function (err, url) {
  console.log(url)
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this url in image tag like this ->

Example of `app.js` or `index.js` file

```
var QRCode = require('qrcode');
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
 QRCode.toDataURL('I am a pony!', function (err, url) {
  console.log(url)
  res.render('index', {qr: url});
  });
});
```

In your template: *(i am using ejs as my template engine)*

```
<img src="<%= qr %>">
```

after this you will get qrcode image instead of qrcode data.
i hope this would help you